# In VS Code, how to search for \{\{[^\s] and replace it with {{\s

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have an Angular project where the HTML contains many text interpolations e.g.

```
{{ somestuff() }}
```

But sometimes the developers forget to obey the spacing convention and write

```
{{somestuff()}}
```

instead.

I want to use VS Code Search and Replace to fix this. Currently I'm doing it in a 4 step process:

1. Search for "{{\s" and replace with "{{"   (Now all the interpolations have {{ with no space.)
2. Search for "{{" and replace with "{{ "
3. And repeat for "}}"

What's a better way of doing this?

[Edit: I should also have mentioned that Prettier would solve this the first time the file is saved...  But our team hasn't yet approved Prettier (although I'm trying to introduce it).  In the meantime, looking for a manual method.]

Comment: Have you considered an actual linting rule? Depending on the tooling you're using you may be able to implement an auto-fix for it too. `@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template` may already have this, or something similar you could base it on.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: replace (Ctrl+H) this: `\{\{\s*(?<txt>[^}^\s]*)\s*\}\}` with this: `{{ $1 }}` using *regex* (click on the `.*` in the replace box; replace all is Ctrl+Alt+Enter). Best solution however is using a linting rule as proposed by @jonrsharpe.

Comment: I'd like to use Prettier, but evilmandarine's q&d solution was exactly what I was looking for, for the moment.  Thanks!

Comment: Find/search: `\{\{\s*([^}]*?)\s*\}\}` and replace with `{{ $1}}`.  `[^}^\s]` isn't quite the right syntax - although it works - the second `^` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jonrsharpe. Here's how you can accomplish that.

1. Install prettier from extensions <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

[image: Prettier VS code extension]

2. Press 
   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows)
   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Mac)
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Linux)
   to format your code

Comment: I totally agree with this, but for the fact that our team hasn't embraced Prettier (yet).  Hence the need for a manual approach - which @evilmadarine has suggested.